# Finding the n-th derivative of an EGF to solve the recurrence

Tags: derivatives, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, power-series, generating-functions

Given recurrence:

${d_{n+1}=n(d_n+d_{n-1}) \\ d_0=1, \ d_1=0}$

I was able to calculate the EGF:

$${\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} d_n\frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{e^{-x}}{|1-x|}}$$

Where the absolute value can be (?) dropped.

Knowing this, normally I would use the Taylor's theorem about 0. So I need to find the n-th derivative of the right part. That's where the problem begins, as these derivatives are not trivial.

**How can I find the n-th derivative of the right part? Is there a better way to solve the problem using an EGF?**

Comment: Hint: Look at the first few derivatives of $f(x)g(x)$

Comment: @Empy2 In derivatives, how do the polynomials next to the e^-x relate to each other? The denominator is trivial. Still, I do not get it.

Comment: For example, the third derivative is $\frac{d^3f}{dx^3}g+3\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}\frac{dg}{dx}+3\frac{df}{dx}\frac{d^2g}{dx^2}+f\frac{d^3g}{dx^3}$.  So find the derivatives of the two parts separately, then combine them using Pascal's Triangle.

Comment: Don't combine the terms until after you have set $x=0$